# $_FILES and $_POST using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

in my form, I added input file.

```
<input name="uploadedFile" type="file" size="50" accept="application/pdf" />
```

And I have this ajax:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result){
       alert(result);
    });
    return false;
});
```

How can I pass the file data to submit.php and upload it using the code in submit.php.  Thanks.

Comment: then, what should i use sir aside from serialize and enumerating all elements inside the form?

Answer (score 7):

jQuery serialize doesn't support file type inputs. From the docs:

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

You will need to roll your own solution using the [HTML5 FileReader API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), to read the contents of the input as a base64-encoded string.

More likely, you will want to use traditional HTML form submission and avoid AJAX altogether for this.

Comment: In addition to serialize, _XHR_ doesn't support file inputs until the introduction of the File API with HTML5

Comment: @ColinMorelli No, I mean *jQuery.serialize* doesn't support file inputs. It has nothing to do with XHR.

Comment: Right. I didn't mean to say "Minor Correction" since it wasn't a correction but rather an addition to your answer. My point was that, even if jQuery.serialize supported files, XHR still doesn't across all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for answering! hmn. 
But, is it possible if there's two action in a submit button. 
   1.  action in the form like action = "upload.php"
   2.  #button.click 
??